# Building deb: How to put arch independent files into separated .deb package?

Tags: debian, compiling

When you build a deb how do you make it so arch independent data such as plugin files to be packaged into a separated .deb?

Comment: This is a very general question that depends on your build system. Are you using debhelper?

Comment: @jordanm Yes, using debhelper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In debian packaging, the `control` file contains the details about the binary packages that the source package will produce. You will need to specify both your arch dependent and arch independent packages in the control file.

Using `debhelper`, you will want your software's build system to install to debian/tmp. How you do this will depend on the build system of the software. For example, if the software's build system uses `GNU autotools`, you would use the following for `debhelper` short rules:

```
override_dh_auto_configure:
        ./configure \
        --prefix=/tmp
```

From there, you want to use `dh_install` to move those files into the appropriate directories for packaging. To do this, you need a file for each binary package named `<package_name>.install`. The file should contain filenames or patterns to be included in the package.

Here is the example provided by the `dh_install` manpage:

> ```
> EXAMPLE
>    Suppose your package's upstream Makefile installs a binary, a man page,
>    and a library into appropriate subdirectories of debian/tmp. You want
>    to put the library into package libfoo, and the rest into package foo.
>    Your rules file will run "dh_install --sourcedir=debian/tmp". Make
>    debian/foo.install contain:
>
>      usr/bin
>      usr/share/man/man1
>
>    While debian/libfoo.install contains:
>
>      usr/lib/libfoo*.so.*
>
>    If you want a libfoo-dev package too, debian/libfoo-dev.install might
>    contain:
>
>      usr/include
>      usr/lib/libfoo*.so
>      usr/share/man/man3
> ```